# UAA deployment on IBM bluemix

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, cloudfoundry-uaa

After deploying [Cloud Foundry UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) on IBM Bluemix, I get following error while accessing the deployed service.

```
Error Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or   DispatcherServlet registered?
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: spring
Error Stack: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered? 
    at   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingF ilterProxy.java:252) 
    at  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
```

UAA is built locally on OSX and Java 8 (1.8.0_025-b17), whereas it is deployed directly on IBM Bluemix Liberty Java.

Comment: The issue is also filed at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues/297

Comment: Thanks to fast reply from uaa devteam, the issue is resolved. It seems Liberty Java searches for flywaydb empty file. Yet to test the solution though!

Comment: Though the above error would go away by employing above solution. This is not sufficient. The code also need to be tweaked for IBM certificates (as UAA would look for SUN certificates). Finally, we deployed using java build pack.

Comment: The fix was really related to IBM Liberty Java, and certificate loading. Switched to Oracle JDK, and deployment worked. We could tweak the UAA source and make it work on Liberty Java. But chose to switch to Oracle JDK instead.